# How can the matrix be changed sparse one or matrix with small entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $m \times n~(m \ge n)$ matrix whose coefficients are in a field $F$.

Is there a $n \times n$ matrix B such that $AB$ is a sparse matrix or $AB$ has small entries?

I guess there exists a matrix $B$. However, I don't know how to get a matrix $B$.

Is there an algorithm to convert another matrix with small entires?

Comment: Well, first you need some notion of "small" in your field. Is $F = \mathbb{R}$ or $F = \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Actually I want to use a field $F=Z_q$ where $q$ is a prime. So, small entries means just small integers such as 1 2..
However, $\mathbb R$ is also ok.